# How can I open Ask Ubuntu chat directly?

Tags: support, chat, faq-proposed

How can I place an icon on my desktop to directly open Ask Ubuntu's chat?

Comment: (Note: [faq-proposed] is to propose [faq] questions for this meta site, rather than be about the /faq page, which is [site-faq].)

Answer (score 7):

Google Chrome supports "web applications" which run in a dedicated browser window: no bookmark bar, tabs, and less UI in general.  These are useful for dedicated windows such as web-based email, feeds, and now [Ask Ubuntu chat](http://chat.askubuntu.com/).  In particular for chat, new links open in a different browser window if you middle-click or otherwise select "open in new tab/window"; this keeps the chat window visible and handy.

Create a new file on your desktop, let's call it askubuntu-chat.desktop, with this content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=AU Chat
Exec=/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --app="http://chat.askubuntu.com/?tab=favorite&sort=active"
Terminal=false
Icon=askubuntu
Type=Application
Categories=Network;WebBrowser;
```

Mark it executable:

```
$ chmod +X ~/desktop/askubuntu-chat.desktop
```

Grab a high quality icon:

```
$ wget http://sstatic.net/askubuntu/img/apple-touch-icon.png -O ~/.local/share/icons/askubuntu.png
```

The launcher name can be customized either in the file ("Name" entry) or on the desktop, and the URL can be whatever landing page on chat you find most useful.  I like the room favorites because I can see any recent activity or use "rejoin all".

Desktop icons:
[image: desktop icon screenshot]

Less UI, handy rejoin button on first page you open:
[image: Chrome window screenshot]

The AU icon is also used for the Chrome window, shown here in the Avant Window Navigator dock:
[image: AWN dock screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

## [Prism](http://packages.ubuntu.com/prism) [image: Install prism]

You can create your chat app by launching Prism from the Internet menu, or directly from Firefox via [Prism extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6665/).

If you are using the extension, visit the chat you want or the main chat page, then click "Tools >>  Convert Web Site to Application" in Firefox menu.

[image: Prism Web App creation tool]

Desktop icon:

[image]

Interface:

[image]